# Paypal Orders PHP SDK: how can I include cacert.pem?

Tags: php, paypal-rest-sdk

I am working to set up PayPal's PHP orders SDK. I am running into `PayPalHttp\IOException: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`.

Which I know to be an issue with me missing the `cacert.pem` file. I've got the file, but I'm not exactly sure how to link it so that PayPal's code can use it.

Nowhere in their documentation does PayPal mention these certificates, so it seems weird that their SDK wouldn't just come bundled with them since they rely on [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL).

I am not otherwise using cURL, so I'm not sure the best way to provide the file path other than to go in and directly modify PayPal's source code which just feels wrong. There is, buried deep in their source code and not mentioned whatsoever in their documentation, the function stub `HttpClient::getCACertFilePath()`, but again, having to modify a third party's source code seems like a bad solution, especially when it could potentially be a different path my development machine to production.

Comment: Just point `curl.cainfo` in your `php.ini` to the certificate bundle as in the duplicate. You should also update `openssl.cafile` to the same value, for libraries not using cURL.

Comment: Re *"it could potentially be a different path my development machine to production"*: One or more words seem to be missing. Please respond by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67307234/edit) (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).